# History on spyder kills the kernel

Tags: python, kernel, anaconda, spyder

My spyder has worked for month but it has suddenly stopped working.
Here is the internal log.

```
/Users/Name_User/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/current.py:19: UserWarning: nbformat.current is deprecated.

- use nbformat for read/write/validate public API
- use nbformat.vX directly to composing notebooks of a particular version

  """)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  [ . . . ]
  File "/Users/Name_User/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/shell.py", line 494, in load_history
    if rawhistory[1] != self.INITHISTORY[1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't get the meaning of the error. Has someone ever faced this problem ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Seems to be an implementation bug. It may make sense to raise an issue at spyder's github repository.

Comment: @cel Tks for your answer. I have raised it on git repo :).

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this is that the history file somehow got truncated or otherwise corrupted. The history file is called `history.py` and it is in the spyder configuration directory, which is `/Users/Name_User/.spyder2` or similar. To solve that problem one needs to remove that file.