# Spyder launch error: IndexError: List index out of range

Tags: python, spyder

I am new to python and currently using spyder 5.3.3 but I have encountered an issue where it will not launch. Please could you help with this.
Error message below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/kira/opt/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/Users/kira/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 252, in main
mainwindow.main(options, args)
File "/Users/kira/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 1956, in main
mainwindow = create_window(MainWindow, app, splash, options, args)
File "/Users/kira/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/utils.py", line 289, in create_window
main.setup()
File "/Users/kira/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 778, in setup
PLUGIN_REGISTRY.register_plugin(self, PluginClass,
File "/Users/kira/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/api/plugin_registration/registry.py", line 342, in register_plugin
instance = self._instantiate_spyder5_plugin(
File "/Users/kira/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/api/plugin_registration/registry.py", line 184, in _instantiate_spyder5_plugin
plugin_instance = PluginClass(main_window, configuration=CONF)
File "/Users/kira/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/api/plugins/new_api.py", line 973, in __init__
super().__init__(parent, configuration=configuration)
File "/Users/kira/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/api/plugins/new_api.py", line 313, in __init__
self._container = container = self.CONTAINER_CLASS(
File "/Users/kira/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/console/widgets/main_widget.py", line 135, in __init__
self.shell = InternalShell( # TODO: Move to use SpyderWidgetMixin?
File "/Users/kira/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/console/widgets/internalshell.py", line 153, in __init__
super().__init__(parent, get_conf_path('history_internal.py'),
File "/Users/kira/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/console/widgets/shell.py", line 665, in __init__
ShellBaseWidget.__init__(self, parent, history_filename,
File "/Users/kira/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/console/widgets/shell.py", line 75, in __init__
self.history = self.load_history()
File "/Users/kira/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/console/widgets/shell.py", line 503, in load_history
if rawhistory[1] != self.INITHISTORY[1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: try this? https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3376

Answer (score 1):

@Kaza, I've just run over the same problem and after a few hours, I found this ([History on spyder kills the kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38990620/history-on-spyder-kills-the-kernel)) that helped me out. In my case, a memory out of space corrupted the history.py file, which can be accessed through spyder defaults at the /Users/Name_User/.spyder-py3 (or under similar file name). Opening that file gave me the option to delete the history.py which resets the file and gets the spyder back to work.